# python 2.7 import a class from the same directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a folder `blimp` with an `__init__.py`, `models.py` and `views.py`

When I import from outside  the folder I use `from blimp.models import ..` but inside folder it gives an import error unless I use `from models import ..`

I was wondering why this is? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are inside the folder and you do :

```
from blimp.models import ...
```

Python try to find `blimp/blimp/models.py`. So it's logic to have the error,

Personally, I always configure correctly my PYTHONPATH in order to have generic import code (no specific python code to manipulate the PYTHON PATH).

To do this, I use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/). When my virtualenv is enable :

```
add2virtualenv directory1 directory2 directory3
```

After that, directory1 directory2 and directory3 are available in the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an order in which Python searches for models. Amongst the paths Python looks for is your current directory (but not the directory above it).

When you are inside your `blimp` folder there is no blimp.models, only a models. The solution is to always run your code from one directory up (e.g. `python -m blimp.stuff`).